# WorkManager se ejecuta múltiples veces al mismo tiempo

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación nativa de Android con Kotlin.

Requiero enviar datos a una base externa a través de un API constantemente, utilicé WorkManager para que cada 15 minutos lea los datos del dispositivo y los envíe; pero, se ejecuta más de una vez y me llena la base de datos de información repetida.

Mi código:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /*
        * Restricciones del trabajo en segundo plano
        * - Requiere una conexión a internet
        * - Requiere que la batería no este baja
        * */
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build()

        /*
        * El método registra el servicio en segundo plano de petición HTTP para enviar los datos
        * almacenados en la DB en un intervalo de 15 minutos
        * */
        val uploadWorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>(
                15,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            ).setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag("montaje").build()

        val workInstance = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)

        // El trabajo se ingresa a la pila de trabajo
        workInstance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("uploadTask", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, uploadWorkRequest)
    }
}
```

Mi worker realiza el post a los datos que tengo almacenados en la base de datos interna del dispositivo, el cual trabaja con la librería OKHTTP:

```
class UploadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker (appContext, workerParameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // El servicio permite registrar los datos almacenados en la DB interna al servidor Web
        setMontajePsd()

        return Result.success()

    }

    private fun setMontajePsd() : Result {

        // Instancia del cliente HTTP
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = OkHttpRequest(client)
        var status : Result = Result.success()

        // PATH API
        val server = "API"
        val path = "WS"
        val url = "$server$path"

        // Instancia y lectura de los datos almacenados en la db interna
        val dbHandler = EscaneoContrato.EscaneoDBHelper(applicationContext)
        val data = dbHandler.escaneosPendientes()

        // Ciclo de los datos almacenados en la DB interna y envío a la nube
        for (montaje in data) {

            // Se construye el objeto
            val map: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf(
                "codigo" to montaje.codigo,
                "verificado" to montaje.verificado.toString(),
                "tiempoInicio" to montaje.fechaInicio,
                "tiempoFin" to montaje.fechaFin,
            )

            // Se realiza el POST del objeto construído
            request.POST(url, map, object: Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("POST", "Request Failure ${e.message}")

                    // En caso de falla, se retorna un failure
                    status = Result.failure()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

                    val responseData = response.body()?.string()

                    status = try {

                        val json = JSONObject(responseData)
                        println("Request Successful")
                        println(json)

                        dbHandler.updateEscaneoEstatus(montaje.id)

                        // Retorna un success
                        Result.success()

                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        return status
    }
}
```

Ocupo la siguiente versión del worker:

```
def work_version = "2.5.0"

implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

Y también dejo una captura de los datos repetidos múltiples veces:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el codigo de tu Worker. De igual forma, la version del Api en el Gradle.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Listo, ya realicé la edición de la pregunta con las versiones que ocupo.